# Generic parameter for overloaded functions in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a wrapper function that takes either `forward` or `backward` because the logic is identical and I want to stick to DRY.

In essence, I want a general function that either uses `forward` or `backward` as the function to apply internally. However, `forward` and `backward` are both overloaded:

```
def forward(String, String): String
def forward(Int, String): Int

def backward(String, String): String
def backward(Int, String): Int
```

Inside my function I want to use something like this:

```
def move[T](f: (T, String) => T, ...) = ???
```

Both versions of `forward` (or `backward`) are used inside `move`. Is there a way to pass in `forward` (or `backward`) to `move` while retaining the overloaded capabilities?

Simplified: `move` returns `( f("text"), f(123) )` and `f` can be either `forward` or `backward`. Is that possible/feasible?

When I try existential types in the parameter type for `f` the compiler obviously doesn't know what type will be returned, so it picks `Any`. I'm not too keen on using a Boolean parameter `isForward` and switch based on that because I still end up copying quite a bit of code.

Comment: Do you need to pass more than one overload to `move` for a single call? i.e `move(forward, backward)`?

Comment: No, the method either uses `forward` or `backward` but it uses both overloaded signatures.

Comment: Probably not because scala is early binding. Perhaps if you make `move` a macro? Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that.